Looking to improve an algorithm for decomposing an integer
I'm interested with primorial number system. In this playful setting, out of curiosity and for relaxation, as an amateur, not knowing the current algorithms for decomposing a $2$-almost prime number $N$ $$N=pq$$I've come up with an algorithm that works well for $N<10^{18}$.
I want to improve the algorithm and your help would be welcome if you don't mind.

To present the algorithm,

1.- I choose $$\boxed{N=221=pq}$$
We have : $221\in 11+30\mathbb Z$ and $ \mathbb Z /30\mathbb Z\approx \mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/3\times \mathbb Z/5 $ and $221\equiv1,2,1 \mod 2,3,5$
I'm looking for $p $ such that $$\begin{cases}p\in (1,1,a) \in \mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/3\times \mathbb Z/5 \\ p>\color{blue}2\times 6 \color{red}{(*)}\end{cases} $$

2.- Here's how I use primorial number system :
We have to solve $$\begin{cases} p\equiv 1 \mod 2 &\color{green}{(a)} \\ p\equiv 1 \mod 3 &\color{Magenta} {(b)}\\p\equiv a \mod 5 &\color{green}{(c)}, \text{ with } a\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}\end{cases}$$
$\color{green}{a)}\exists k_0\in \mathbb Z, p=\color{blue}1+2k_0 $
$\color{Magenta} {b)}1+2k_0=1$ in $\mathbb Z/3Z$. So, $k_0=0+3k_1$. So, $p=\color{blue}1+\color{blue}0\times 2+6k_1$
$\color{green}{c)}1+k_1=a$ in $\mathbb Z/5$. So, $k_1=a-1+5k_2$
So, $p=\color{blue}1+\color{blue}0\times 2+\color{blue}{(a-1)}\times 6+30k_2$
According to $\color{red}{(*)}$, We just have to look at the cases $a=3,4,5$.
For $a=3$, ie $p=\color{blue}1+\color{blue}0\times 2+\color{blue}{2}\times 6=13$, what is written in Primorial number system$$\color{blue}{(2:0:1)}$$ it matches since $$\boxed {13\times 17=221}$$

Question: As I wrote, this algorithm works well for numbers below $10^{18}$, as the computation times then become too high on my PC.
I.- Could this be of mathematical interest to push it beyond this limit ?
II.- If not, can this be explained simply to an amateur like me? (I know almost nothing about complexity calculations for example)
III.- And if so, how? (in the notes, I indicate that I already have an idea)

Note :

I use a subroutine that provides me with the inverses and allows me to solve the simple modular equations that appear as I go along.

This algorithm makes me interested in how to multiply in Primorial number system.

With very large numbers, the algorithm must be forced to consider only a reasonable number of cases because of the computation times; Hence the idea of the constraint $\color{red}{(*)}$, which I still haven't put into practice in the python program I made.

I've done a lot of rating abuses for modular arithmetic calculations and there are notations clash. But they are so common that I thought they would not be very difficult.



Edit: To reply to @Peter's comment, the same technique appplies to $$N=40\,014\,989\,856\,514\,759$$
$$N\in (1,1,4,2,9,8,5,2)$$
For the computer, it matches with $$\begin{cases} 
p\in (1,1,2,1,8,8,6,13)\\ q\in (1,1,2,2,8,1,15,6) \end{cases}$$
We find $$\boxed{200\,018\,827\times 200\,056\,117}$$
(this is a document on which I had written "1 min" for my computer to provide the result)

To wake the interest of other users , demonstrate how you factor , say , a $16$-digit semiprime without a small factor this way. If this works efficiently (say being able to compete with known efficient methods like the quadratic sieve) , someone will surely examine it deeper.

Just for reference, using Mathematica running on a  on a Raspberry Pi 5 it takes about $\frac{1}{1000}$ of a second to factor $40014989856514759=200018827 \cdot 200056117$.

I find your algorithm description hard to follow, but perhaps posting your Python code would help to clarify your algorithm.

Could you please characterize the properties of the integers for the "cases chosen by me"? Also, its not clear to me how you determine $p\in (1,1,a)$ or $\begin{cases}
p\in (1,1,2,1,8,8,6,13)\ q\in (1,1,2,2,8,1,15,6) \end{cases}$ in your two examples. In your first example you introduce the variables $b$ and $c$ but never seem to use them, and the meaning of $p\equiv 1 \mod 3 (b)$ for example is also not clear to me.

@StevenClark : Thank you for your interest. That's a lot of questions. I will try to answer them gradually. First, $N=221\equiv1,2,1 \mod 2,3,5$. So $N=pq\in (1,2,1)$. The only possibilities for $p$ and $q$ are $(p\in (1,2,c) \land q\in (1,1,d))$ or  $(p\in (1,1,a) \land q\in (1,2,b))$. These two possibilities are "symetric". I chose to look for $p\in (1,1,a)$.

I'm not sure I understand your notation. For example assuming $\mathbb Z$ is the set of integers, what does $221\in 11+30\mathbb Z$ mean? Does this mean $\exists k\in \mathbb Z: 221=11+30 k$? Assuming the notation at Modular arithmetic-Integers modulo m, by $\mathbb Z /30\mathbb Z\approx \mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/3\times \mathbb Z/5$ do you mean the integers modulo $30$ can be derived from the integers modulo $2$, $3$, and $5$ via the Chinese remainder theorem?
